# Replace assembly in ASP.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

I am trying to (mostly to see if it can be done) replace a dll-file in a ASP.net application. And just to make things more interesting, the file I'm trying to replace, is the same file that will (to a certain degree at least) hold the logic of how to replace it.

I've been able to replace almost every file in the project, except for the dll-files that are running, and currently I'm a bit stuck.

First of all, this is not something that should be performed often, so scalability is not an issue (doesn't matter if it takes up to a minute or so). Secondly, I do not want to use a Windows Service.

The only way (I have yet to try, but will start experimenting with) to achieve this (without using a Windows Service) is to create an application that is launced by the ASP.net app. Then the ASP.net app shuts itself down (using something like `HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain();`), hopefully this will unlock the files. Then the application swaps out the dll-files. However I'm thinking that there must be some other possible way to achieve this.

So what I'm asking is basically for ideas on how to solve this problem, because I'm about to run out of mine.

Comment: So you want to do this without recycling the app pool?

Comment: No, I'm ok with recycling the app pool (given I understand the meaning of it). As long as I don't need to enter IIS Setup, it should be ok. Restarting the app itself was something I figured I had to do anyways, and it's not a biggie.

Comment: Just copy the new dll's (assemblies) in to the BIN folder and it should just restart itself.

Comment: I'm telling you, it doesn't work. I can't overwrite the existing files, because they are locked.

Comment: Are these .NET assemblies or native DLL's?

Comment: Actually, you are right. It seems I've been doing something terribly wrong and trying to swap the temporarily copied out .dll-files used by ASP.net. It's now working just perfect. Thank you very much :).

Comment: No problem, glad it is solved now ;p

Comment: A much easier way to do this is to have two ASP.Net applications in different IIS sites, update one version and then switch their bindings. Then next time switch again, and on and on. Just mentioning in case you this would fit your requirements.

Comment: It sounds like that would result in a fairly high overhead with regards to setup, and switching would probably have to be done manually (not by the ASP.net app itself), which was sort of the purpose.